# I am getting this error org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to use hibernate with spring boot. But I am getting this error: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder.
I am a beginner trying to learn spring boot. Any help would be much appreciated.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdetails
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class EclinicReportBeanConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.eclinic.report" });
        return factory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory factory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(factory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Here is my dao file :

```
@Repository
public class DHAReportDaoImpl implements DHAReportDao {

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<UserSetup> getAllUserDetails() {

        String hql = "select userId, userName from UserSetup";
        Query<UserSetup> query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
        List<UserSetup> userlist = query.getResultList();

        return userlist;
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }

}
```

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: please provide stacktrace of error

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case the problem was with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` - use `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: this annotation is to be given in db configuration?

Comment: springboot launcher class below this @SpringBootApplication

Comment: is it this class EclinicReportBeanConfig ?

Comment: Yes i gave it in EclinicReportBeanConfig.